# Empty set as limit

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a small category and $C \in \mathbf{C}$. We can construct a limit in
$S$ in $\mathbf{Hom}(C, -): \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{Sets}$ as follows

$$
S = \left\lbrace k \in \prod_{D \in \mathbf{C}} \textbf{Hom}(C, D) \ \middle| \ \forall \alpha\colon i \to j \in \mathbf{C}. \, \alpha \circ k_i = k_j \right\rbrace
$$

I've already proved that this is the limit in $\mathbf{Hom}(C, -)$, but now I'm trying to find a concrete category where the limit is the empty set for all $C \in \mathbf{C}$.

Edit:
Some informal  description about S. Let $i \in \mathbf{C}$. Each $k$ contains a morphism $C \to D_1$, a morphism $C \to D_2$, etc. for all $D_i \in \mathbf{C}$. When I write $k_i$ I mean a function in $\mathbf{Hom}(C, D_i)$. That is, $k_i: C \to i$. Then $S$ is the set of morphisms with domain $C$ for which the condition $\alpha \circ k_i = k_j$ holds. Hope it clears things up.

Comment: Your notation is a tad unclear. Could you check your definition of $S$?

Comment: I added some info on the notation. As far as I know the definition I wrote of $S$ is correct.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "limit in $\text{Hom}(C, -)$." What do you mean by a limit in a functor?

Comment: Oh. I might have been too fast on that one. If we consider the functor $\mathbf{Hom}(C, -)$ as a diagram in the category of Sets, we can use this functor to create a Cone, and S is the limit of this Cone.

Comment: @Lie: Please edit your question accordingly. Have you read the answer? Please accept it if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a category consisting of two isomorphic sets $A_1\cong A_2$, of cardinality at least 2, and all possible isomorphisms and automorphisms between them (it forms a groupoid).

For any $f_1,f_2 \in \text{Hom}(A_1,A_1)\times\text{Hom}(A_1,A_2)$, since there is guaranteed to be an automorphism $g$ of $A_1$ such that $g \not= f_1$, then we have $f_1 \not= (gf_2^{-1})f_2$, so $(f_1,f_2) \notin S$.